# Sending XCM messages

Tags: ink, xcm

Is there a way to send XCM messages from ink! contract?

If it is not possible, what are the other options for sending XCM messages(I suppose you can send XCM messages from a substrate pallet but is there another way)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ink! extension](https://ink.substrate.io/macros-attributes/chain-extension/) to call any pallet, which itself can send XCM messages.
You can have a look at [these pallets](https://github.com/LaurentTrk/sublink-pallets) as an example, but please be aware that this is just a crappy hackathon code :)